# Reviewing suggested edits -- Which column is the original, and which is the proposal?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing the suggested edits queue, I came across this one and I'm confused.  My understanding is that the post on the left side is the original and the right side is the proposed changes, correct?

The comment says the edit fixes formatting and removed extraneous/sarchastic material, but the one on the right side is the one with the garbage in it.  Is the editor being a jackass or am I reading this backwards?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the case. The original is on the left, and the proposal is on the right.

About the actual review, it appears to me like it is an auto-generated audit (genuine edit summary and looking genuine at first but actually intending to vandalize) made by inserting random words using the Markov-chain algorithm. To pass this audit, you'd need to reject this edit as vandalism ("this edit appears to be spam, defaces the post in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate").

Comment: Ahhhh an audit. Gotcha. Well I navigated away from the page to post the question here. Does that mean I passed or failed? LOL

Comment: @WesSayeed Go back to the previous page, and it should show again.